# Questions that are too specific?

Tags: discussion, closing, flags

Similar to [this meta question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8212/how-to-deal-with-how-should-one-counter-x-questions-in-moba), I'd like to figure out what to do about a scenario where multiple extremely similar questions are asked but have minor differences.

For an example, see these two questions: [Question 1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/165418/enchant-which-weapon-property-attack-speed-or-damage) & [Question 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/164205/enchant-weapon-property-favor-attack-speed-or-damage)

Both of these questions (Diablo 3) are asking about weapon enchantment:  If a weapon has both Increased Attack Speed and +% Damage, and the player wishes to enchant the weapon to remove one of these two stats to replace with a slot, which is more important?  That base point is identical in both questions.  The difference is that **Question 1** deals with a mace being used by a Barbarian class in a Whirlwind spec while **Question 2** deals with a crossbow being used by a Demon Hunter class.  Class and build may subtly change what target attack speed values to aim for and possibly whether attack speed is important at all (channeling builds aim for high dmg and attack speed is unimportant).

I claim that the two questions are duplicates, and that a good answer would detail **why** each stat may be important, how to determine for your class/build which to aim for, and let the asker figure out for themselves where to go from there.

My concern here is that we'll end up with many different 'identical' questions but each one is being asked by a person playing a different class or slightly different build.  This makes it difficult to find an answer for people searching, especially since the question titles don't detail the differences.  Hell, in the examples provided, the titles are practically identical: "Enchant Which Weapon Property: % Attack Speed or % Damage" vs "Enchant Weapon Property: Favor Attack Speed or % Damage?".

**TLDR:** If two or more questions are nearly identical with only minor differences due to build/class/etc should we close them as duplicates and prefer more generic answers that inform the asker so they can determine for themselves in their specific scenario what to do, or allow there to be tens of questions with only those minor differences?

Comment: I think build/class is pretty important in regards to which stat to drop on a weapon. I'd prefer 10 expert answers for different builds than one genericised answer that boils down to "it depends what you're building and your own playstyle"

Answer (score 1):

I thought about this for a while before casting my vote to close it as a duplicate.

For me, it came down to this: The questions are either way too specific so as to be useless to anyone else ("Hey, look at THIS PARTICULAR ITEM and tell me what's best for me") or they're a more general discussion on how one should prioritize IAS vs %Damage, in which case they are duplicates of each other. If the former, that's pretty much the definition of "too localized", though to be fair, I guess that's not actually a close reason anymore. If the latter, then the second should be closed as a dupe of the first. In either case, in my mind, closing was appropriate.

A valid point that I hadn't considered was raised in that different classes might treat these differently, and that limiting the scope of the question to a single class (Demon Hunter in the first case, Barbarian in the second) will provide better answers since then someone doesn't have to be an expert on all six classes to properly answer the question. I could see reopening it on those grounds and wouldn't vote to close it again, though personally I feel like the theory behind which to choose is general enough that that level of fidelity isn't strictly needed.

If people are thinking we actually need a separate question for every single build, then I believe the correct action would be to vote to close as "Unclear what you're asking" until they post the full details of their build, including all passives. Personally I think that would be overkill, but if we're thinking that we want to answer this on a per build basis, then we had better demand that they provide us with the information to do so, since just saying something generic like "I'm using a whirlwind build" could mean a lot of different things.

Comment: This was pretty much my line of thinking, plus the thought of having tons of questions for every specific build (given the sheer variety of **good** builds, much less avg/poor ones) being pure clutter and making every question too localized and worthless to everyone except that particular asker - which isn't really what the stackexchange is about.