# How can we draw attention to old meta discussions?

Tags: discussion, questions, meta

I really like this site and how most of the rules here are working, but there are some things that are rather unclear. I often find myself in a situation where I want to ask a meta question about rules but after looking for it (mainly because I feel like I can't be the first who thinks like this), I find a 2-3 years old meta thread that has around 1 or 2 up/downvotes. Often this applies for things where I think that it's Important to find a solution as the community  of this site (Example [External Resources](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1811/where-do-website-questions-fit-in-our-scope/) or [Extremely Similar Questions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8212/how-to-deal-with-how-should-one-counter-x-questions-in-moba)).

In Forums you usually have the ability to bump something. The problem is that while meta is a discussion platform, it's also still a Stackexchange site. This means if you just post an answer it's a non-answer, a comment doesn't bump and an edit would be invalid. Also I usually try to avoid creating duplicates of already existing questions (sometimes it happens though. A lot of topics are well hidden...)

So is there a way for me to draw attention to a post that I find Interesting but neglected?

Comment: For some meta questions, the [faq] tag accomplishes this, however, it seems to be used very slightly.

Comment: First, dupes are not a bad thing.  If you have trouble finding the original, odds are others will too.  Duplicates can help those users find the original question as well.  Second, site policies change over time.  Just look at all the meta discussions about our stance on lore/story questions.  However, you should always put in some sort of research effort before asking.

Answer (score 2):

When the subject becomes relevant in a discussion just bring the link to the table.